# Why no errors from multiprocessing is reported in Python and how to switch on reporting errors?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I setup some simple code to test some problem handling with multiprocessing and I can not track the bug inside this code because not feedback from processes. How can I receive exception from subprocesses since now I am blind to it. How to debug this code.

```
# coding=utf-8
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers
import logging

def callback(result):
  print multiprocessing.current_process().name, 'callback', result

def worker(io_lock, value):
  # error
  raise RuntimeError()
  result = value + 1
  with io_lock:
    print multiprocessing.current_process().name, value, result
  return result

def main():
  manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
  io_lock = manager.Lock()
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
  for i in range(10):
    print pool.apply_async(worker, args=(io_lock, i), callback = callback)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
  main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try, catch, and log exceptions that occur inside your worker processes. Something like this

```
def worker(io_lock, value):
    try:
        raise RuntimeError('URGH') # Or do your actual work here
    except:
        logging.exception('Exception occurred: ')
        raise  # Re-raise the exception so that the process exits
```

The exception log handler will automatically include the stacktrace.

Comment: Looks that simple solution is the best solution. I am testing how it works with 16 processes.

Comment: I've modified my answer slightly, you should probably also re raise the exception after you've logged it. That way the process will crash and exit properly. Of course you might NOT want that behaviour. But I would advise it.

Comment: That is true exception should raised again after logging since was not handle - you are right that is the best pattern.