# Sharing dictionary in multiprocessing with python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

In my program I need to share a dictionary between processes in multiprocessing with Python. I've simplified the code to put here an example:

```
import multiprocessing
def folding (return_dict, seq):
    dis = 1
    d = 0
    ddg = 1 
    '''This is irrelevant, actually my program sends seq parameter to other extern program that returns dis, d and ddg parameters'''
    return_dict [seq] = [dis, d, ddg]

seqs = ['atcgtg', 'agcgatcg', 'atcgatcgatc', atcggatcg', agctgctagct']
manager = Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
n_cores = 3

for i in range (0, len(seqs), n_cores) #n_cores is the number of cores availables in the computer, defined by the user
    subseqs = seqs[i:i + n_cores]
    processes = [Process(target=folding, args =(return_dict, seq)) for seq in subseqs]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

for i in retun_dict:
    print i
```

I expected to have at the end of the program the return_dict with all of the property values. 
When I run my program, that has to do this with seqs list of thousand of sequences and repeat it lot of times, sometimes I get the correct result, but sometimes (the most part of the times) the program never ends, but retuns any error, and I have no idea what is going wrong.
Futhermore, I think that this is not very efficient in time, I wanted to know if there are other way to do this most efficiently and faster.
Thank you every body!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With fixing some minor syntax errors your code seems to work.

However, I would use a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead of your custom solution to run always `n_cores` processes at a time. The problem with your approach is that all processes need to be finished before you start the next batch. Depending on how variable the time is which you need to compute `folding`, you can encounter a bottleneck. In the worst case, this means no speed up whatsoever compared to single core processing.

Moreover, your program will run into serious problems under Windows. You need to make sure that your main module can be safely imported without re-running your multiprocessing code. That is, you need to protect your main *entry point* via `if __name__ == '__main___'` which you might have seen already in other python scripts. This will make sure that your protected code will only be executed if your script is started as the *main* file from the interpreter, i.e. only once and not by every new child process you spawn.

Here is my slightly changed version of your code using a pool:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def folding(return_dict, seq):
    dis = 1
    d = 0
    ddg = 1
    '''This is irrelevant, actually my program sends seq parameter to other extern program that returns dis, d and ddg parameters'''
    return_dict[seq] = [dis, d, ddg]


def main():
    seqs = ['atcgtg', 'agcgatcg', 'atcgatcgatc', 'atcggatcg', 'agctgctagct']
    manager = mp.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    n_cores = 3

    # created pool running maximum 3 cores
    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores)

    # Execute the folding task in parallel
    for seq in seqs:
        pool.apply_async(folding, args=(return_dict, seq))

    # Tell the pool that there are no more tasks to come and join
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Print the results
    for i in return_dict.keys():
        print(i, return_dict[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Protected main function
    main()
```

and this will print

```
atcgtg [1, 0, 1]
atcgatcgatc [1, 0, 1]
agcgatcg [1, 0, 1]
atcggatcg [1, 0, 1]
agctgctagct [1, 0, 1]
```

---

### Example without Shared Data

**EDIT:** Also in your case there is actually no need to have a shared data structure. You could simply rely on the [pool's map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) function. *map* takes an *iterable* which is then used to call the function `folding` with all elements of the iterable once. Using *map* over *map_asnyc* has the advantage that the results are in order of the inputs. But you need to wait until all results are gathered until you can process them.

Here is an example using *map*. Note that your function `folding` now returns the result instead of putting it into a shared dictionary:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def folding(seq):
    dis = 1
    d = 0
    ddg = 1
    '''This is irrelevant, actually my program sends seq parameter to other extern program that returns dis, d and ddg parameters'''
    # Return results instead of using shared data
    return [dis, d, ddg]


def main():
    seqs = ['atcgtg', 'agcgatcg', 'atcgatcgatc', 'atcggatcg', 'agctgctagct']
    n_cores = 3

    pool = mp.Pool(n_cores)

    # Use map which blocks until all results are ready:
    res = pool.map(folding, iterable=seqs)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Print the results
    # Using list(zip(..)) to print inputs next to outputs
    print(list(zip(seqs, res)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this one prints

```
[('atcgtg', [1, 0, 1]), ('agcgatcg', [1, 0, 1]), ('atcgatcgatc', [1, 0, 1]), ('atcggatcg', [1, 0, 1]), ('agctgctagct', [1, 0, 1])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!your tips looks so useful! I'm trying both in my program and it looks like works fine. I'm using LINUX so I don't have the __main__problem, it's more dificult to implement because the multiprocessing is into another function more complex, it's a large program!

Comment: Hello again, I tested both options yesterday and only worked the second option (without shared data), but the first didn't end. I ran both options under the same condictions and I don't know what is happening, please someone have any idea?

Comment: Maybe your workers crash when you assign data to the shared dictionary. You could try to use logging to see if and how your workers did crash. Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697173/why-no-errors-from-multiprocessing-is-reported-in-python-and-how-to-switch-on-re) is an example of how to log errors in child processes and to get the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Another idea, you said you actually call another software to do the (protein?) folding. Maybe that one gets stuck/crashes by chance, and you were just unlucky in the first case!?

Comment: I'll try the logging, thak you. Yes, the other software (RNA folding) could crash, but I chatch this errors with stderr, so I'm pretty sure that it is not the problem, almost is not always the problem.

Comment: I'll try again with both solutions and again, the code seems not work with large number of sequences. I really have no idea what's happening

Comment: IThe most reasonable answer is that your calling to the external folding program is the source of the error. I guess it is getting stuck in an infinite loop and does not crash. How do you call the external programm, via `os.system` or via a `subprocess`? If the latter you can simply state a timeout via `join` and kill it if it runs too long.

Comment: I call it via subprocess. This via works when I run the program without the multiprocessing. Yes I'll try the timeout via join() and doesn't work either. I'm sorry about the waste of time, but I tried to fix the problem for a long time reading lots of manuals and I don't know what to do

Comment: Well, if it runs single core, maybe it's a memory issue. Does your folding program need a lot of memory? I.e. starting several folding operations in parallel may require more memory than you have in RAM? Thus, if your OS starts swapping, the runtime can become almost endless.

Comment: Yes, maybe this can be the problem. I'm trying to find other solution (or other problem) because I asume that if the problem is the RAM requeriments, the only solution is change the computer